# Do accepted answers count as a "point" towards associated tags?

Tags: support, tags

I know +1 votes count towards your score for associated tags, but I wanted to know if that is true for accepted answers too.

If so, I assume its considered 1 point?  Also, if the asker +1 votes the answer and accepts it, does it give you +2 to the tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### If the asker +1 votes the answer and accepts it, does it give you +2 to the tag?

No, it does not.

> **What is this tag score you speak of?**
>
> A tag score is basically the combined total of all the upvotes (+1)
>   and downvotes (-1) you've accumulated on answers under that specific
>   tag (votes on questions do not count). **Acceptance of an answer
>   doesn't have any weight in the score**. As well, posts which are in
>   community wiki status or that have been deleted do not count towards
>   your tag score. Tag scores are only recalculated once daily, at 03:00
>   UTC.

Source [What are tag badges? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63836/267099)

Comment: Thank you for the source!